# java script for button click recognition

Tags: javascript

How can i check whether a button is clicked or not using javascript

Comment: write alert in the function which you are calling so that u will get an bit idea

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a `<button>`, use the onclick event.
The dirty way to do so would be `<button onclick="your javascript here">...</button>`.

The clean way is registering an event handler from your javascript code. e.g. if you are using jQuery in this way:

```
$('#id-of-your-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* do something */
});`
```

The preventDefault() call ensures no side-effects like submitting a form occur. When using the dirty inline way, you can achieve that by ending the code with `return false;`.